# unable to resolve class org.apache.commons.net.ftp in grails

Tags: grails, apache-commons

I am developing a module in which some file need to be uploaded on a ftp server for that I have added the "commons-net-3.3.jar" in my grails app & while using it

```
import org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTP
import org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTPClient
import org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTPClientConfig
import org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTPFile
import org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTPReply
```

It is throwing the error unable
 to resolve class org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTPReply.
In ggts I am able to see all the classes of this package but it throw the error at runtime. What can be the possible solution for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Grails you rarely add jar files to the project, you normally add dependencies. In your case you should add this line to the `BuildConfig.groovy` (section `grails.project.dependency.resolution.plugins`)

```
compile 'commons-net:commons-net:3.3'
```